# Email addresses as account primary keys

Tags: email, security

This may not be the right place to ask but I figured if I wanted experts in this type of infrastructure this might be the sort of place that would have some.

I've hit a wall with the CTO.

Essentially I have a back end which uses a SSO model and I'm being told that "email addresses are basically a primary key reference to a user" since multiple accounts cannot share an email address.

The example I've spent all morning pointing at Microsoft's Auth structure which "asks" the user for an email address then list all accounts with that address for you to choose from then authenticate with a password, other providers that are following the OAuth standards are following a similar UI structure too.

The CTO seems to be inferring from this that the email address is basically identical to a userId (the primary key used to identify the user in the entire SSO environment), and having a separate PK is therefore "a pointless over complication that Microsoft just does for some BS reason".

Typical examples of my concerns ...

1. The reuse problem:
   There are people and even small businesses that share an email address. And like phone numbers, emails can get re-used. Jsmith@somecompany.com can easily belong to John Smith one year and Julia Smith two years later.
2. The update problem:
   Another problem with emails is that they change frequently. If you are joining to other tables with that as the key, then you will have to update the other tables as well which can be quite a performance hit when an entire client company changes their emails (which I have seen happen.)
3. The Multiple accounts problem:
   I have an account with Microsoft that I created when I joined the company to link my MSDN sub to.
   Later the company got an Azure subscription and created me an account linked to the same email address.
   The boss claims these should be seen as the same account and therefore my org should manage that as it owns the @mycompany.com domain.
4. The multiple solutions problem:
   I have an email address, I sign up to use an app in our CMS with that address.
   I later sign up to use another app in our CMS (so same SSO, different client of our company).
   Is that the same account, which admins of those apps can "manage my account"?
5. The multiple providers problem:
   I have an email address linked to my Facebook, google, and Microsoft accounts, I want to link these to my corporate account so that I can sign in with these credentials, they all share an email address but they are also multiple remote accounts ... what if I want to link them to different local accounts and use the remote email address for all correspondence in our system?

To my mind email addresses have no business being treated as a primary key for anything substantial and even less so for something as crucial as a security model, the boss disagrees.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: It feels like everything you've said makes sense, and you know this, but nothing helps clarify the mind like writing a topic out for a third party `:-)`

Comment: From a security perspective, email addresses are valuable and should not be splashed around all over the place without very good reason. Organisations should move away from using email addresses as login credentials.

Comment: @Martin i completely agree ... but why? It's like the whole industry agrees "lets not do that guys ..." then does it anyway all over the place.

Comment: because many people believe security is "how to make the end user feel secure" rather than "how to actually protect the end user". Security is using different systems to protect against different threats; a long password protects against automated login attempts, a shorter password with crazy symbols protects against human login attempts. It is down to **you** to research and implement best practise, despite things like Google and Facebook absolutely not using best practise for some of their various security practises.

Answer (score 0):

as your wording "since multiple accounts cannot share an email address." seems to imply that email should be *Unique* not a *Primary Key*.

Unique constraints are not the same as Primary Keys and as you already figure out, email is a very bad Primary Key.

Primary key should be [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). I tend to think that [Natural keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) are never good candidate for Primary Keys on a DB.

Comment: I'm not wording it that way ... my boss is ... I disagree with that statement altogether as per some of my typical concerns section.